# how to decode search string %..%.. php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, search

when i press search russian word a after page load i get like this 
`%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD`.

"**сапсан**" is default searh word.
How to search the russian word above, not symbols ?
**сапсан**

```
< input type="text" name="keyword" autocomplete="off" class="sp-vmsearch-box" value="%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD" placeholder="Search"> - not correct

< input type="text" name="keyword" autocomplete="off" class="sp-vmsearch-box" value="сапсан" placeholder="Search"> - correct value
```

after page reloaded

Comment: Please provide your code

Answer (score 0):

How is the value set to the input? via $_GET/$_POST? may you must use http://php.net/manual/de/function.urldecode.php

Comment: <input type="text" name="keyword" autocomplete="off" class="sp-vmsearch-box" value="<?php echo JRequest:: getVar('keyword') ?>" />
        How to decode this variable ??? (value)

Comment: just use the php function `<input type="text" name="keyword" autocomplete="off" class="sp-vmsearch-box" value="<?php echo urldecode(JRequest:: getVar('keyword')) ?>" />`